# Collection<Integer> cannot be converted to int while using Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, type-conversion, java-stream

I want to do a `Map<Person, Double>`, where `Double` is average of `Integer` values that is stored in another `Map <String, Integer>` which is one of the fields of stream's elements.

```java
public Map<Person,Double> totalScores(Stream<CourseResult> programmingResults) {
    return 
        programmingResults.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            CourseResult::getPerson,
// And there is a problem, I want to get values from `Map <String, Integer>` 
// and do the `averagingInt`, but only get 
//`Bad return type in lambda expression: 
// Collection<Integer> cannot be converted to int`

            Collectors.averagingInt(
                s -> s.getTaskResults().values()
            )
        ));
}
```

How can I get these values in the right way?

There's some of the classes I'm using:

```java
public class CourseResult {
    private final Person person;
    private final Map<String, Integer> taskResults;
    
    public CourseResult(final Person person, final Map<String, Integer> taskResults) {
        this.person = person;
        this.taskResults = taskResults;
    }
    
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Integer> getTaskResults() {
        return taskResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got to add a `flatMap` to get from a logical `Stream<Collection<Integer>>` to a `Stream<Integer>`.  There's some added complication from needing to take along the `String`, though.

Comment: Are there really multiple `CourseResult` instances for the same `Person`, so that you need *grouping*?

Comment: @Holger Actually no. There is only one `CourseResult` for each `Person`.

Comment: Then, `toMap` makes your life easier (as the answers also point out now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `values()` is a `Collection<Integer>`. You can't average by that. You can use a flat-mapping `Collector`, to flatten each group of persons to just integers, rather than `CourseResult`. After that, you can do an average by the identity function.

```
return programmingResults.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        CourseResult::getPerson,
        Collectors.flatMapping(s->s.getTaskResults().values().stream(),
            Collectors.averagingInt(x -> x)
            )
    )
);
```

Edit: If there is only one `CourseResult` per `Person`, then you don't need `groupingBy`. Just use `toMap` and calculate the average using another stream.

```
return programmingResults.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        CourseResult::getPerson, 
        result -> result.getTaskResults().values()
            .stream().mapToInt(x -> x).average().orElse(0))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that the input stream contains `CourseResult` instances which have unique persons (and grouping + flatMapping of the task results may not be needed), it may be sufficient to use `toMap` collector:

```java
public Map<Person,Double> totalScores(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return 
        results.collect(Collectors.toMap(
            CourseResult::getPerson,
            cr -> cr.getTaskResults().values() // Collection<Integer>
                .stream() // Stream<Integer>
                .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::intValue))
            )
        ));
}
```